# CUDA program return random result

Tags: c, cuda

This is my kernel function and it does simple work:
`&` every item with `blockIdx.x` to filter even and odd:

```
__global__
void g_compact(const unsigned int* v_array, unsigned int* compact_array, int size)
{
    const int p_index = blockIdx.x * size + threadIdx.x;

    if ((v_array[threadIdx.x] & 1) == blockIdx.x)
    {
        compact_array[p_index]= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        compact_array[p_index]= 0;
    }
}
```

However, it produce random result every time I run the program, like

`1  0  1625730008  32767  1625730024  32767  4197775  0  0  0  4197470  0  0  0  2525809656  32630  1  0  1625729712  32767`

What confuse me is that the result is not `0` or `1` since my `if` and `else` should cover every situation.

Could someone help me out of this?

Total program:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_array(const unsigned int* v_array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<v_array[i]<<"  ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

__global__
void g_compact(const unsigned int* v_array, unsigned int* compact_array, int size)
{
    const int p_index = blockIdx.x * size + threadIdx.x;

    if (true)
    {
        compact_array[p_index]= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        compact_array[p_index]= 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned int *d_in;
    unsigned int *d_out;

    cudaMalloc(&d_in,  sizeof(unsigned int) * 10);
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(unsigned int) * 20);

    unsigned int h_array[10] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 10
    };

    cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_array, sizeof(unsigned int) * 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    g_compact<<<2, 10>>>(h_array, d_out, 10);

    unsigned int h_out[20];
    cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, sizeof(unsigned int) * 20, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    print_array(h_out, 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good cuda error checking would have helped you giving you clues on what was happening, maybe you could have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api  for your future CUDA developments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how you write your kernel function but how you call it:

```
unsigned int h_array[10] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8,
    9, 10
};

cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_array, sizeof(unsigned int) * 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

g_compact<<<2, 10>>>(h_array, d_out, 10);
```

You pass a host pointer (`h_array`) to a kernel function. How does it suppose to work?

I think you want to change `h_array` to `d_in`

```
g_compact<<<2, 10>>>(d_in, d_out, 10);
```